# What are my options for Web 2.0 gallery software?

Tags: cms, photo-gallery, community

My question is: What are my options if I need a Web 2.0 gallery software that work in a very similar manner to this *removed* web site. Essentially: users can create account, then create and manage their own galleries. And all other users and guests can see these galleries, add tags, comments, etc. Basically a community driven gallery web site.

When it comes to "normal" cms I know a lot of good options, but I never worked with any gallery management software... If you can suggest me some good solutions (free) it would be great!

Also: If you by any chance know what software is used at this *removed* website it would be even better, because this solution suits me the best and I would have used this engine, but I cant find any information on what this engine is and if it is even public, or privately developed thing.

Comment: Who is so smart as to vote down my post and not say anything? :)

Comment: Try asking them. Personally, I like Coppermine, but there are many more available.

Answer (score 0):

I use this for a lot of my sites, its fairly lightweight, it's easily customizable, and it seems to be fairly well supported. Check it out [Plogger](http://www.plogger.org/)